# Is this a bug of clang 13 on [[likely]] attribute?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, attributes, c++20, compiler-bug

The following code is accepted by *gcc 11.2*, but rejected by *clang 13*:

```
struct A
{
    int n = 0;

    constexpr operator int() const noexcept
    {
        if (n >= 2) [[unlikely]]
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else if (n >= 1) [[likely]]
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else [[unlikely]]
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{}
```

The *clang 13*'s error message:

```
error: no return statement in constexpr function
    constexpr operator int() const noexcept
              ^
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/69Gdezqvz

**Is this a bug of clang-13 on** `[[likely]]` **attribute?**

Comment: This bug seemed to have been [reported](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50205) by me before which was fixed in trunk.